# Steps to manipulate XLS to JSON like this

Tags: json, excel

Very new to SwiftUI and reading data from JSON files, but getting there.  Could experts in the community advise please how I get from the data in Excel to the format required in JSON.

In Excel I have this...

[image]

... and what I would like from that data in Excel is for my JSON file to be like this...

[image]

Could someone advise the steps I'd need to take to get from a to b please.  Wondering if this can be done in one step, or if it has to be multiple.

Essentially the code I am writing needs to select 'n' questions from each SylabusItem.  So in this example, Question 1 in the exam would need 2 questions presented to the student from a selection of those with the same SylabusItem. So, in this case 2 from 3. Subsequent questions will vary of course.

Thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in one step with a VBA function easily enough.

```
dim dataToWrite(0)  'Normally, I'd dim this as dataToWrite() then use a function to ascertain if empty or not, then either redim(0) or redim preserve (ubound+1) on down. But for succintness just ignoring that.

'Get the lastRow of your data 
sheetName1 = activesheet.name  'Obviously change that to whatever suits
LastRow = Sheets(sheetName1).Cells(Sheets(sheetName1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

for iRow = 2 to lastRow 'Assuming that you have header sheet in first row
    if not isempty(Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,1)) then
        'Have a Qn entry here
         redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)

        'Do our prefixing
        dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = "["
        redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)
        dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = vbTab & "{"
        
        redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)
        dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & """"Qn"""" & ":" & """" & Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,1) & """"
        redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)
        dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = vbTab & vbTab vbTab & & """" & "Level" & """" & ":" & """" & Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,2) & """"

        'etc, over to answers, then
        corrAnswer = -1
        DoUntil IsEmpty(Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,5))
            redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)
            dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & """" & "Answer" & Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,5) & """" & ":" & """" & Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,6) & """"
            if Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,7) = "y" then
                corrAnswer = Sheets(sheetName1).cells(iRow,5)
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Loop

        if corrAnswer = -1 then
            'We didn't find a correct answer, problem
        else
            redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)
            dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & """" & "CorrectAnswer" & """" & ":" & """" & corrAnswer & """"
        end if
        'And close out
        redim preserve dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)+1)
        dataToWrite(ubound(dataToWrite)) = vbTab & "}," 
next iRow

'Then write out dataToWrite to your text (json) file
Dim filePath As String
filePath = "C:\temp\MyTestFile.txt"

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Dim fileStream As TextStream

Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath)

for iLine = 0 to ubound(dataToWrite)
    fileStream.WriteLine dataToWrite(iLine)
fileStream.Close
```

Thats not complete obviously, and something I've just scribbled down on this page so untested - and likely to have some pythonic stuff in by accident. But should be the bare bones of what you are looking for.

Sorry - forgot your looking the indents. Apply a suitable number of vbTab to the string line,

Comment: Great advice Amiga500 (I had one of those, think I still have it somewhere in the attic!!), thanks.  This is a tad advanced for me though... appreciate your taking the time to reply though.  Thank you.